# Linksys SRW248g4p Latency Issues

Tags: networking, latency, linksys

Pinging between the linksys the ping times are averaging 40ms. I have evening tried pinging between two Linksys switches that are connected to each other directly using the GB ports. 
There have no modification done to the switches and the firmware seems to be up to date.

What could be causing the latency problems? The reason for asking this question is that we have a VoIP system and the latency seems to be causing voice quality issues.

Comment: "Any suggestions would be appreciated." -- Any question would be appreciated too.

Comment: What model are your Procurves? Also are they manageable so you can check on the link speed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having 40ms ping times between switches in your LAN, you have some horrible misconfigurations going on.  Check all your cabling, etc.

Comment: im betting some wiring loops